# Why am I getting this error trying to create these methods?

Tags: c#

I am trying to initialize 3 different methods and getting the error.

> this variable does not exist in the current context

I'm thinking its because of scope but I don't see how I can change the `calculatebmi()` or `calculateextime()` methods without messing them up.

How do I get rid of this error? It is complaining about `oldbmi`, `time`, and `newbmi`.

Related Code:

```
public partial class Program2 : Form
{
    private double _height;
    private double _weight;
    const int caloriesBurned = 10000;
    const int walkingSpeed = 4;
    const double fatCaloriesPerPound = 3500;
    const double metricWalkingSpeed = walkingSpeed / .62137;

    private double calculateBmi(double metricWeight, double metricHeight)
    {
        double oldBmi = metricWeight / Math.Pow(metricHeight, 2);


        double newMetricWeight = metricWeight - (caloriesBurned / (fatCaloriesPerPound * 2.2046));
        double newBmi = newMetricWeight / Math.Pow(metricHeight, 2);

        return oldBmi;
    }

    private double calculateExTime(double metricWeight, double metricHeight)
    {
        double exerciseMultiplier = .0215 * Math.Pow(metricWalkingSpeed, 3)
                                  - .1765 * Math.Pow(metricWalkingSpeed, 2)
                                  + .8710 * metricWalkingSpeed
                                  + 1.4577;
        double time = caloriesBurned / (exerciseMultiplier * metricWeight);

        return time;
    }


        private void displayresults( double _height, double _weight, double oldbmi,double time, double newBmi )
        {
            double newWeight = _weight - (caloriesBurned / fatCaloriesPerPound);
            int feet = (int)_height / 12;
            int inches = (int)_height % 12;
            HeightText.Text = string.Format("{0}ft {1}in", feet, inches);
            Weight.Text = _weight.ToString();
            OriginalBmi.Text = oldBmi.ToString("F2");
            NewBmi.Text = newBmi.ToString("F2");
            NewWeight.Text = newWeight.ToString("F2");
            ExerciseTime.Text = string.Format("{0} hrs {1} min", (int)(time), (int)(time % 60));
        }




 displayresults(_height, _weight,oldBmi,time,newBmi);
```

Comment: *Which* variable is it complaining about, and *where*? You've currently posted over 120 lines of code - please reduce this to a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: And now you've removed *so much* that there's no indication of what variables you've got in your class. I asked for a short *but complete* program. *Are* you declaring the variables the compiler is complaining about? If so, where?

Comment: So where are you calling the method `displayresults`?

Comment: Its at the bottom of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be in your call to the displayresults method. You're referencing oldbmi, newbmi, and time there, but none of these objects exist in that scope, because they're defined locally to calculateBmi. This is an assumption on my part - you haven't really shown the context of the code in which you call calculateBmi - but it seems to be the case.

If you want the oldBmi and newBmi values you calculate in displayresults() to be usable elsewhere in the program, you need to create private fields or public properties at the class level, like you have for _height and _weight. Then you can set this.newbmi to the value you calculate, rather than creating a new double in that scope which never gets used.

So instead, the top of your class would look like this:

```
private double _height;
private double _weight;
private double oldbmi = 0;
private double newbmi = 0;
const int caloriesBurned = 10000;
const int walkingSpeed = 4;
const double fatCaloriesPerPound = 3500;
const double metricWalkingSpeed = walkingSpeed / .62137;
```

and your calculateBmi method would look like so:

```
private double calculateBmi(double metricWeight, double metricHeight)
{
    this.oldBmi = metricWeight / Math.Pow(metricHeight, 2);


    double newMetricWeight = metricWeight - (caloriesBurned / (fatCaloriesPerPound * 2.2046));
    this.newBmi = newMetricWeight / Math.Pow(metricHeight, 2);

    return oldBmi;
}
```

and you can call displayresults with this.oldbmi and this.newbmi.

You should know that nearly everything in your code is against the .NET naming conventions. Variables shouldn't begin with '_', consts should be CamelCase, private fields should be pascalCase, and methods should always be CamelCase. Please take a look through this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/618ayhy6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx. Many people here follow these conventions and it'll make it easier for you to get help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method `displayresults` which takes some parameters.

Whenever you call a method you need to pass values a/c to the `DataType` of the method's parameters. It is not necessary to pass the variables with exact names as the method has (I think you have a confusion with that).

So the right syntax will be like:

```
displayresults(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
```

**OR**

If you want to pass variables you should have them in the current context:

```
double _height = 10;
double _weight = 20;
double oldBmi = 30;
double time = 40;
double newBmi = 50;

displayresults(_height, _weight, oldBmi, time, newBmi);
```